# Azure Logic App check if Mail Item is a reply

Tags: azure

I'm using Azure Logic App Office 365 Outlook connector - "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)", is there a way to find out if an incoming email is a Reply or not ?

In my case I need to check if an incoming email is a "New" email, not a reply.